# can I set UIButton a tag with letter？

Tags: ios, swift

I encountered a puzzle. I have many buttons. I want to set tag for them respectively, but it seems that tag can only be set as a number, which is inconvenient for me to read the code. I want to set a name similar to “abc”. Is there any way or other way

[image]

Comment: Instead of using tags I would recommend using `IBOutlets`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own property like this

```
extension UIButton {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var stringTag = "stringTag"
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var stringTag: String? {
        get {
            guard let stringTag = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.stringTag) as? String else {
                return nil
            }
            
            return stringTag
        }
        
        set(value) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.stringTag, value, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @liangdapang please use updated code.

Comment: I seem to have another problem. When I set different "string tag" for different buttons, I use print(sender.stringTag )  I get the same result ??why? thanks

Comment: Please check the updated code. I already mention @liangdapang

Answer (score 2):

No, tag is integer type

```
var tag: Int { get set }
```

**But there is alternative way to do this.**

Firstly create a class -

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var customTag:String = ""
}
```

And then you can use it as -

```
let btn = CustomButton()
btn.customTag = "abcd"
btn.backgroundColor = .green
btn.setTitle("your title", for: .normal)
```

Comment: Can I use other ways？ For example, similar Identifier?

Comment: I have edited my code, please check.

Comment: Please upvote if it helped.